# How to capitalize button text like “Add to Cart”?

Tags: magento2.4.1

Right now my 3rd party theme shows "Add To Cart" which means every first letter of a word is cap.
I want Magento 2.4.1 to display all buttons in capital letters.
For example Add To Cart -> ADD TO CART, Place Order -> PLACE ORDER etc.
I would like to make changes in the CSS and not translation files.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Translation files would be the right way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `CSS`. Use CSS `text-transform` property with `uppercase` value.
Put the below code in your `CSS` file for `Add To Cart` and `Place Order` text. If you want to change more texts then just add the `element` `selector` in `CSS`.

```
.action.tocart, .payment-method button.action.checkout {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: There are so many .css and .less files. How can I find out which one is the right one to edit?

Comment: Which Magento theme you have used?

Comment: This one: http://mageblueskytech.com/rubix/en6/

Comment: You can use this CSS file. pub/media/rokanthemes/theme_option/custom_en6.css

Comment: Got it! Cheers!

Comment: It should go in your theme at web/css/source/_extend.less. Magento automatically imports _extend.less files and they are there for this purpose